# What is Crystal's Char::Reader defined as a Struct and not a Class?

Tags: crystal-lang

[Char::Reader](https://github.com/crystal-lang/crystal/blob/master/src/char/reader.cr) is defined in the standard library as a `Struct`. What was the reasoning behind choosing a `Struct` instead of a `Class`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that was choosen for performance reasons. According to the [docs](https://crystal-lang.org/docs/syntax_and_semantics/structs.html):

> A struct is mostly used for performance reasons to avoid lots of small memory allocations when passing small copies might be more efficient.
>
> So how do you choose between a struct and a class? The rule of thumb is that if no instance variable is ever reassigned, i.e. your type is immutable, you could use a struct, otherwise use a class.

`Char::Reader` is mutable (because has instance variables reassigned), but it seems to be safe enough to do what the compiler internals do even if `reader` is a struct:

```
reader = Char::Reader.new(pattern)
while reader.has_next?
  char = reader.current_char
  reader = check_char reader, char
  reader.next_char
end
```

Comment: Thanks. Also, the stdlib JSON lexer (for strings) also uses it as an instance var (ie `@reader = Char::Reader.new(str)`) where it mutates it as a reference: `@reader.next_char`.  Source: https://github.com/crystal-lang/crystal/blob/master/src/json/lexer/string_based.cr